# Why are compact/bounded varieties finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I read this in a script and want to know the proof. Even if my intuition says it's totally clear, I can't find a proof on my own.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand the question. For the most obvious interpretations of the words "compact" and "finite", this is false: think of projective space. (I don't know what "bounded" is supposed to mean.) Where did you read this?

Comment: well, sorry, my english isnt that good. I mean compact/bounded in the metric topology on C^n

Comment: Dear Mark, it is not a question of English. Anyway, now I understand: you are talking about subvarieties of $\mathbb C^n$. That wasn't clear before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought every variety is in C^n

Comment: Dear Mark: indeed, that is a natural idea. But your question provides a good reason why we want to consider varieities that _cannot_ live inside $\mathbb C^n$: namely, we would like to have compact varieties that aren't just finite sets of points. This is the motivation for the invention of _projective space_.